# Delete/disable constraint during animation

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I have a rope made of rigid bodies with constraints in between each one to connect them and I would like one constraint to be disabled during the animation so that the rope splits in the middle.

How can I disable or delete the constraint so that it connects two rigid bodies at the start of the animation but then disconnects at another point in time?

So instead of deleting it outright, I would like it to be removed at a specific point during the animation.

(Note that I'm still a beginner at Blender)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to delete the constraint - its' also not possible to animate this way.
Instead, you animate the breakable parameter of the constraint. Set the threshold value very low, and insert keys(I key or right click menu) to switch breakable on on a frame where you want.

[image: find the breakable parameter here:]